# Vue event handler sometimes getting $event object passed and sometimes not

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a situation like this: In a component called "ProductForm" I have a method "addToCart", which will add some product to a cart in an online shop. This is called via button click event.

Now I added a new child component "GiftUpsell", which is essentially just an additional "Add to Cart" button. But it should additionally add another product, passed as parameter to handleAddToCart.

So I modified the handleAddToCart method in ProductForm to accept an optional parameter, as below, and I pass this parameter via an event from the child component "GiftUpsell":

ProductForm.vue

```html
<template>
  <btn @click.native="handleAddToCart">Add to Cart</btn>
  <gift-upsell @upsellAddToCart="handleAddToCart" />
</template>

<script>
import GiftUpsell from '~/components/GiftUpsell'

export default {
  components: { GiftUpsell },
  methods: {
    handleAddToCart(upsellLineItem = null) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

GiftUpsell.vue

```html
<template>
  <btn @click.native="upsellAddToCart">Add to cart with upsell</btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    createUpsellLineItem() {
      // whatever
      return some object;
    },

    upsellAddToCart() {
      const lineItem = createUpsellLineItem();
      this.$emit('upsell-add-to-cart', lineItem);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem now is: When I use the new upsell add-to-cart button, it works fine. The `lineItem` parameter is passed as the *only* parameter to `handleAddToCart` and the logic works.

When I, however, click on the old, "normal" add-to-cart button, the `handleAddToCart` method gets the `$event` as first parameter - which is not present when `handleAddToCart` is called via the `upsell-add-to-cart` event.

This is confusing. Why is the $event parameter present when I don't need it, and only the event parameters present (but not event object) when I need the parameters? Is there a way to get rid of this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v-on` directive automatically passes the event data to the specified method when only a method name is given. That's what occurs for both `@click` bindings in your template, and that's also what enables the emitted data (`lineItem`) to get to `handleAddToCart`.

These two templates are equivalent:

```html
<btn @click.native="handleAddToCart">Add to Cart</btn>
<gift-upsell @upsellAddToCart="handleAddToCart" />
```

```html
<btn @click.native="handleAddToCart($event)">Add to Cart</btn>
<gift-upsell @upsellAddToCart="handleAddToCart($event)" />
```

In the first `<btn @click>` binding, the button's `click` event data (the `MouseEvent`) is passed as the argument to `handleAddToCart`. To make the `<btn>`'s click pass nothing instead, you could update the binding to call `handleAddToCart` without arguments:

```html
<btn @click.native="handleAddToCart()">Add to Cart</btn>
<gift-upsell @upsellAddToCart="handleAddToCart" />
```

Or be explicit for both `v-on` bindings:

```html
<btn @click.native="handleAddToCart()">Add to Cart</btn>
<gift-upsell @upsellAddToCart="handleAddToCart($event)" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the parameter I passed in $emit would/should be something different than (additional to) the $event object passed to a handler, and wondered why the $event was missing in the first place when passing this parameter..

Comment: Indeed, @trollkotze, one might think it works similar to the filters and `value` parameter. Related: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: "The v-on directive automatically passes the event data to the specified method when only a method name is given" - [The documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#method-handlers) says otherwise, see comment ``// `event` is the native DOM event`. Could be that I read something wrong, but I think your answer and the documentation contradict, and I think you are right.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Hmm. I don't understand. How does "`event` is the native DOM event" contradict my answer?